# add facebook login in NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript

I am very new in mobile development and native script, i am trying to add facebook login to my app and followed steps given in https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-facebook-login

nativescript-facebook-login module added successfully in /node_module folder also updated AndroidManifest.xml file as mentioned in above url..

while building the app via **tns run android**  i am getting below message
"**Skip com.facebook.applinks.FacebookAppLinkResolver
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException"**
though build succeed but nothing delploying in my android phone

at the end command terminates with below error
***The package archive file is invalid.***
Sending exception report (press Ctrl+C to stop).....

any suggestion?? or is there any alternate to achieve facebook-login in nativescript??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin called facebook-login that does work. I use it in my ThisOrThat app. Take a look at this repo: https://github.com/jlooper/thisorthat-app

Comment: Thanks, your app helped me on this